# Jquery autocomplete, cannot read non-English letters

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I used the following tools

https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

but it cannot read arabic letter or Kurdish letter, it only reads English.

but when, I try arabic letters or Kurdish letters, it cannot read.

var countries = {
    "کو": "کوردستان",
    "tttt": "ttttt Test",
    "AE": "United Arab Emirates",
    "AF": "Afghanistan",
    "AG": "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "AI": "Anguilla",
    "AL": "Albania",
    "AM": "Armenia"
}

Comment: You can save file as utf-8 supported then its working